# Show JSON Data in Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I've been trying to get my JSON data in jQuery DataTables component.

First I wrote the JavaScript code as well as a view as shown in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myData').DataTable({
        lengthChange: false,
        ajax: {
            url: "http://amp-local/api/wipbin/FetchChild/",
            // dataSrc: 'allk'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "numbers" }
        ],
        select: true
    });
});
```

My view:

```
<table id="myData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Numbers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My JSON:

```
[{
    "numbers": "38",
    "name": "Bllaca"
}, {
    "numbers": "28",
    "name": "Kaess"
}, {
    "numbers": "27",
    "name": "droessmer"
}, {
    "numbers": "24",
    "name": "friedricha"
}]
```

Result is with this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.length')
```

And my table is empty.

Comment: your JSON is invalid.

Comment: How should be ?

Comment: You're missing `}]` on the end

Comment: ahh because I show only part of my json

Comment: Ok well just add the `}]` anyway... it is ok to limit it but it has to be valid in your examples at the very least.

Comment: Is the JSON you posted definitely the **actual** response to the ajax request? It could be a response issue.

Comment: yes this is the ctual response to the ajax request

Comment: According to the online docs, the syntax should be E.G.  `"ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'` ?

Comment: If you go to the url `http://amp-local/api/wipbin/FetchChild/` in your browser, what comes up on the page?

Comment: The JSON result

Comment: Ok, have you tried the above syntax I mentioned?

Comment: How ? I take the info directly from query this is something how change each Hour

Comment: Instead of putting`ajax: {
            url: "http://amp-local/api/wipbin/FetchChild/",
            // dataSrc: 'allk'
        }`

Comment: put `ajax: 'http://amp-local/api/wipbin/FetchChild/' `

Comment: Look here https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: I try it same error no changes

Comment: this the error:   jquery.dataTables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:48
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Could you share your server response?

Comment: https://snag.gy/U0Z2rs.jpg

Comment: @Sofiane , please show response body that returned from `http://amp-local/api/wipbin/FetchChild/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using server-side processing with AJAX requests, it expects JSON data to be returned in the [special format](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) required by DataTables. The following fields of JSON response object are required: `draw`, `data`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered`. You need to bring your server response into accordance with [expected format](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).
For example, your first response should be as following:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 4,
  "recordsFiltered": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "numbers": "38",
      "name": "Bllaca"
    }, {
      "numbers": "28",
      "name": "Kaess"
    }, {
      "numbers": "27",
      "name": "droessmer"
    }, {
      "numbers": "24",
      "name": "friedricha"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How can i change this ? direct on the query ?

Comment: @Sofiane, this is requirements to **server** response. You need to change this on server side.